# siebel log clarification - queries running twice

Tags: siebel

I am analysing the siebel log and i see that every query runs twice in the log. Could anyone pls tell me why this happens?

For example the below query is one of the many queries that i found got executed twice in the log

```
SELECT /*+ ALL_ROWS */
  T2.CONFLICT_ID,
  T2.LAST_UPD,
  T2.CREATED,
  T2.LAST_UPD_BY,
  T2.CREATED_BY,
  T2.MODIFICATION_NUM,
  T2.ROW_ID,
  T1.BU_ID,
  T2.MULTI_LINGUAL_FLG,
  :1
FROM 
   SIEBEL.S_LST_OF_VAL_BU T1,
   SIEBEL.S_LST_OF_VAL T2
WHERE 
  T2.ROW_ID = T1.LST_OF_VAL_ID (+) AND
  (T2.TYPE = :2 AND T2.NAME = :3)
ORDER BY
  T2.TYPE, T2.ORDER_BY, T2.VAL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query should NOT run twice, unless the logged in user has repeated an operation, and the Business Component is not cached. You will see the SQLs for LOV values repeated in the log,  but the value of bind variable ":2" will be different each time. You can see these values just under the SQL

eg: Bind variable 2: TIME_ZONE_DST_ORDINAL
Bind variable 2: DAY_NAME

Is there any other SQL which is repeated and not for the S_LST_OF_VAL tables ?